# Get available attributes (possibly recursive) from JSON Schema in Java

Tags: java, json, jsonschema

Let's say I've got the following JSON Schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/product.schema.json",
  "title": "Draft JSON Schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
      "person": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
              "details": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                      "first_name": {
                          "type": "string"
                      },
                      "last_name": {
                          "type": "string"
                      },
                      "groups": {
                          "type": "array",
                          "items": { "$ref": "#/$defs/existing_groups"
                      }
                  }

              }
          }
      },
      "$defs": {
          "existing_groups": [ "Teachers", "Students" ]
      },
      "book": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
              "title": {
                  "type": "string"
              },
              "author": {
                  "type": "string"
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

From this schema, I would like to retrieve the available attributes and values at a defined depth:

- So what's given is e.g. `person.details` and I want `first_name, last_name, groups` to be returned.
- If `person.details.groups` is given, the possible values `Student, Teacher` should be returned.
- If `book.title` is given, an empty `Array` or `Set` should be returned.

Apparently you can get attribute values from `JSON` objects with `JsonPath`, but I rather want to get possible attributes (and their possible values, if any are given) from a `com.networknt.schema.JsonSchema`.

What is the easiest way to do this in Java?

Answer (score 0):

JSON Schema is for validating data. It has nothing to do with data manipulation or extraction. It's not comparable to JSONPath in any way.

Comment: I just mentioned JSONPath to illustrate that I am looking for something similar for a schema. I know that JSON schema is not the same as JSON. In my case, I am working with a JSON schema and I need to extract the attributes that are allowed according to this schema.